# C# Change the name of the assembly dynamically on application startup

Tags: c#, .net

I have searched tons for an answer and here is what I have tried:

- Renaming the Executables filename doesnt change the processname in task manager.
- I already know I can go into the C# project properties to change the assembly name. But this doesnt solve my proble (because I need to change the assembly name each time the application starts.)

Here would be a sample code (obviously not executable):

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Assemblyname = $Randomstring;
}
```

Essentially, I would want the applications processname that appears in task manager to be something different every time it starts.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm extremely curious - what could possibly be a viable, non-malicious use case for this?

Comment: @squillman one usecase maybe; see the `svchost.exe`s in task manager. It would be good if they have a name showing what they are doing (Am i too naive :) )

Comment: Dont play coy, you know exactly what this is for. :)